# Endless loop in jQuery and PHP. What should I change to make it work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<?
if($_POST['begin'])
{
    while(1)
    {
        echo "1";
        sleep(2);
    }
    die();
}
?>

<span class="answer"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "exp.php",
            data: "begin=1",
            success: function(msg){
                $(".answer").html(msg);
            }
        })  
})
</script>
```

It, of course, doesn't work. What should I change to make it work? Can I avoid using setInterval, setTimeout or other functions in javascript?

By the way, what I am trying to do here is to write number 1 every two seconds.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Define "working" in this scenario.

Comment: This cannot be done without using Javascript.

Comment: Start changing `while(1)` to `while(0)`. This definitely will remove infinity loop.

Comment: @Jon, that's true, but since he's tagged the question 'javascript' and 'jquery,' and has asked about '[avoiding] using setInterval, setTimeout or other functions in javascript,' I think he's realised that.

Comment: When you call PHP it will go into an endless loop and your javascript callback will not get fired. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong approach, because your success function isn't going to run until it receives a response from the server which isn't going to happen as it's in an endless loop.

You will need to handle the timings in JavaScript with, as you say, setInterval. Of course if all you're trying to do is simply print the number 1 every five seconds you don't need to make any calls to the server-side (although I presume there's something more you're trying to achieve eventually - you might want to expand on that a little).

You could look into opening a WebSocket back to the server do handle this kind of ongoing communication. Look into something like PusherApp - http://pusher.com/

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried it, but the XMLHttpRequest interface supposedly supports streamed requests. In particular there is the `.readyState==3` which denotes partial results (See spec http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-handler-attributes).

When you don't want to set an interval handler, then you will have to override the actual XHR callback, because the jQuery `success:` will really only fire on completion.

```
xmlHttp = $.ajax({ ... });

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState >= 3) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

Note that the responseText will always contain the accumulated data. So you have to split it up on `\n` or something, if you want to read the latest `1`.

Comment: This might actually work. You might need to add a flush() statement to the PHP script (after printing '1').

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I know what you want. It's weird .. but fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fetch_a_one() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "exp.php",
            data: "begin=1",
            success: function(msg){
                $(".answer").html(msg);
                fetch_a_one();
            }
        })
    }
    fetch_a_one();
})
</script>
<div class="answer"></div>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
sleep(2); // way two seconds
exit(1); // print 1
?>
```

Minus some delay from starting the Ajax request and lag from the server, this should print '1' every 2 seconds .. no idea why you want this.

Comment: I was going to +1 this as it fits how the OP wants to approach things - but I don't think that handling the 2 second timer on the server is a good idea. It ties up a process on the machine for a significant amount of time when it can't do anything else.

Comment: It's the only way to make a 2 second wait in Javascript without using setTimeout or setInterval .. I'm not saying it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to use JavaScript for this.  You can continually poll the server resource to get information from it, but the actual looping and delaying will need to be in JavaScript.

The reason for this is because the PHP script needs to *finish* processing at some point.  It's not streaming output to the client, it's building output to send to the client.  In the code you provide, it's forever building the output and never sending it.

You can try to [flush your buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) from the PHP script to send some output to the client while still building more output, but take a look at the caveats in that link.  It's not really a *clean* way to accomplish this and will probably cause more problems than it solves in this case.  At some point the server resource needs to stop processing and commit to a response.  Trying to short-circuit that basic concept of HTTP will likely be a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you're writing endless PHP loop.

jQuery when starting ajax request, will be waiting for script to finish his job. However the script would never ends - so the browser will never get the full answer.

You need to use setTimeout, there is no other way - at least no other easy and safe way.